# The Horizontal Force of Water as it turns 180 degrees

Tags: fluid-mechanics

For a National Board Exam Review:

> A uniform area jet travels to $600 \frac{ft}{s}$ and a
>   $100\frac{ft^3}{s}$. What is the horizontal force acts on the water jet
>   if it undergoes a $180^\circ$ turn?

I would normally provide an answer but even review instructor cannot answer question...

So I try:

$${ F_x = \frac{ \gamma Q }{ g } \left(\nu_2 \cos(\theta) - \nu_1\right)}$$
$${ F_x = \frac{ 62.4 \frac{lb_m}{ft^3} ( 100 \frac{ft^3}{s} ) }{ 32.2 \frac{ft}{s^2} } \left(600 \frac{ft}{s^2} \cos(180^\circ)- 0\right) = -116273.2919\,lb_f }$$
Is the negative sign logical? All choices are from the range of ${1.35*10^5}$ to ${ 5.32*10^5 }$ lbf

Comment: May I assume that "with a flow of" is missing in the description? I can not explain the `100` otherwise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved easily by calculating momentum.  Momentum is mass x velocity.  Force is momentum / time.

Answer (score 0):

Try considering the force required to stop the jet, then the same force again to accelerate the jet back to the same velocity, but in the opposite direction.